# How to hover over a div element to show popup containing text from object properties

Tags: javascript

I'm making a webpage that takes in api data an provides a js array of object to work with. I'm already using the object array properties to create anchors in a div box that are named "a0", "a1", ... ect. What I'd like to do is be able to hover over a specific anchor to display a text box containing information from the related object properties. Example "a0" would correspond to Object[0]. So by hovering over "a0", I would display Object[0].properties in a div box.

Since this is API data, I'd like to avoid hard coding this. I'm really not sure what the best way to accomplish this is.

I've researched a few different ways and most seem to revolve around hardcoding the CSS to display based on ID, but I'm not sure how to display a DIV box which contains object properties that is called on hover over a specific element.

//assume that alerts is already populated with an array of objects.

```
var alerts = [];

var i = 0;
        for (var x in alerts) {
          var a = document.createElement("A");
          a.id = "a" + i;
          a.class = alerts[x].severity;
          a.innerHTML = alerts[x].title;
          document.getElementById("sidebar").appendChild(a);
          i++;
        }
```

Comment: You want to display the text box on `hover` of anchor tag and text box should be pre-populated with the text of anchor. This is what you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm trying to display specific object properties on hover over a correlated div or anchor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use data attributes for this. For each anchor tag, add additional data attributes for data you want to show in the popup. You can read more about data attributes here: [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Then, add mouseover handlers for the anchor tag. In the handler you can read values from the data attributes for the anchor and use them to populate the div you want to show on hover

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```js
var alerts = [{
    severity: 1,
    title: "abc",
    properties: "property 1"
  },
  {
    severity: 2,
    title: "def",
    properties: "property 2"
  },
  {
    severity: 3,
    title: "ghi",
    properties: "property 3"
  }
];

var i = 0;
for (var x in alerts) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  var div = document.createElement("p");
  a.id = "a" + i;
  a.class = alerts[x].severity;
  a.innerHTML = alerts[x].title;
  div.innerHTML = alerts[x].properties;
  a.appendChild(div);
  document.getElementById("sidebar").appendChild(a);
  i++;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

a p {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: tranlate(-50%, -50%);
}

a:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">


</div>
```

Comment: This is really close to what I'm trying to do. If there a way to use this method but have the text that pops up on hover appear fixed in the center of the screen

Comment: Updated the answer a bit . See if it suits you